# How can i make a role specific command in discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've been searching and tried pasting and modifying about everything on this website but here goes:

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.content == "?status on") {
        if (message.author.roles.has(578319894039232558)) client.user.setActivity(`0.4.4 | ?help | being cool`);
    }
});
```

I want to make only the owner of the server be able to turn the status from boot (none) to turning on no matter what I try it cant make role-specific.

Answer (score 1):

[`message.author`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author) returns a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) object, which has no `roles` property.

You are looking for [`message.member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member) which returns a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) object.

Another mistake I spotted is that you need to use strings for IDs. [Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179)

---

## Discord JS Version 12+

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.content == "?status on") {
        if (!message.member.roles.cache.has("578319894039232558")) return false;
        client.user.setActivity(`0.4.4 | ?help | being cool`);
    }
});
```

## Discord JS Version 11

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.content == "?status on") {
        if (!message.member.roles.has("578319894039232558")) return false;
        client.user.setActivity(`0.4.4 | ?help | being cool`);
    }
});
```